# Connect socket server then send message using JAVA

Tags: java, websocket, socket.io

I'm using Postman to test Chat feature (socket.io technology with version 2).
Currently, i have to implement Chat test cases using Java.

**Postman request information:**

1. Socket server: https://hc-socketio-example.xyz

2. Header.authorization: xxx

3. Header.source: app

4. Message.text with JSON format:

```
{   "ticketId": "63bcc910c22293b4b0495fe4",   "content": "test ",   "type": "text"}
```

**My Java code to connect socket server:**

```
    URI uri = URI.create("https://hc-socket.unibag.xyz");
    // @formatter:off
    IO.Options options = IO.Options.builder().build();

    // @formatter:on
    Socket socket = IO.socket(uri, options);
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            System.out.println("Connected to server...");
        }
    });
    socket.connect();
```

**My issues need the help:**

1. Look like my code gets wrong because no String "Connected to server..." printed.
2. I don't know the way to set the header or request: "authentication", "source"
3. I'm not sure the way to send JSON message like above:

COULD SOMEONE TAKE A LOOK AND GIVE ME THE ADVISE IN ORDER I COULD FIX MY CODE?
THANKS A LOT IN ADVANCE.

I tried researching on the internet some examples but no luck. I'm confusing about the way to send socket request.

Answer (score 0):

Chats are typically facilitated through web sockets over http, assuming you want to build a chat system that runs over the internet.

I have a working program written that can establish a connection and send/receive messages from the Chat Server.

As a prerequisite you need a third party library.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also accompanied is the piece of client code that can send headers, get acknowledgement for connections and send/receive json messages

```
public class ChatWebSocketClient extends WebSocketClient{

public ChatWebSocketClient(URI serverURI, Map<String, String> headers) {
     super(serverURI, new Draft_17(), headers, 0);
        
       
    
}

@Override
public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void onMessage(String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception ex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();
    headers.put("header1", "value1 for header1");
    
    ChatWebSocketClient client = new ChatWebSocketClient(new URI("Remote_Chat_EndPoint"), headers);
    
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
        }
        
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
    }};
    
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    client.setWebSocketFactory(new DefaultSSLWebSocketClientFactory(sc));
    client.connect();
    
    client.send("{\"key\":\"Hello World\"}");
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. But i tried to download dependency org.java-websocket version 1.3.0 and look like no luck because dependency not found.
Could you share me the full of code. Because i could not try with above code. Something failed at loading class like Draft_17()

Comment: The classes like Draft_17 or WebSocketClient are found in the underlying jar fetched from above Maven dependancy.  You can check out https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.java-websocket/Java-WebSocket/1.3.0 and see that dependancy exists in Maven repo. There are many versions available. Try any of it, it should work.